# Is it possible to ask too many questions?

Tags: discussion

Throughout any given day, I will wonder many, many things. An absurd amount of things, actually, so much so that it's really impossible for me to research everything that I want to know about. Linguistics is one of these topics that I think about way too much. ***Way too much.***

I think most of these could be answered by this community, and it would be generating a good bit of content since this StackExchange has a low questions-asking rate. Is it possible to ask too many questions?

Comment: You may also find this discussion useful: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60462/asking-too-many-questions

Comment: Also, this: http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 3):

It really comes down to the *quality* of those questions. As long as you keep asking good questions, you can ask as many as you want. By "good questions", I'm referring to the general guidelines of Stack Exchange: on-topic, not too localized nor too broad, showing previous effort, and eliciting definite answers (not opinions, preferences, etc).

You are right. We need more questions per day and you have been asking interesting questions lately. Maybe you could flesh out those questions and increase their overall quality. This would certainly have a very positive impact on our metrics!

Comment: There is a limit though. I can't find the exact numbers, but there is a limit per day and per month.

Comment: Also our votes will teach you which of your questions we consider good ones and which we consider bad ones, that should help you hone your question asking skills here.